# Free street parking in Paris

Tags: budget, automobiles, paris

I'm going to stay in Paris for 18 hours approx (from 18:00 on Thursday until 11:00 on Friday). and I found closed car parks for €30 per day, which is ok. The problem is that I might want to use the car once to go other places nearby, so I plan to park in the street during the evening, and then leave the car in the car park overnight.

Are there any areas in Paris with free parking in the street (maybe a map)? The hotel I'll be staying is in the area of Montmartre.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not an answer to your question but could be a practical solution to your problem: Street parking, where allowed, is free from 19:00 to 09:00. You will only be staying a couple of hours at each end of this time period so you can simply pay a few euros when arriving to bridge the time until 19:00 and pay again before going to bed for the two hours in the morning. In total, you would pay much less than €30. I did just that a few months ago and it went fine. I think you will need a credit card.

If you are able to find a parking spot (this might be the difficult part) and you are not concerned about the safety of the area, there is no reason to go to a car park overnight. I have also heard that some streets are still completely free but parking is not that expensive and relatively unrestricted compared to other European cities so it never seemed worth the trouble.

Some official info in English: [parisinfo.com](http://en.parisinfo.com/how-to-get-to-and-around-paris/your-arrival/by-car)

[Paris.fr](http://www.paris.fr/pratique/stationnement/payer-le-stationnement/stationnement-les-principes/rub_5779_stand_70906_port_12654) also provides some info, unfortunately only in French as far as I can tell. What you would be using is the “tarif visiteur”:

> **Le tarif visiteur**
>
> Il s’applique à tout visiteur sur l’ensemble des voies parisiennes ouvertes au stationnement payant, ainsi qu’à tout titulaire d’une carte de stationnement résidentiel sur les voies de régime rotatif ou en dehors des 4 zones de stationnement résidentiel qui lui ont été attribuées.
>
> Le stationnement au tarif visiteur est limité à deux heures consécutives au même emplacement.

Translation/summary of the relevant bits: The visitor price applies to all streets opened to paid parking. […] Parking as a visitor is limited to two hours on the same spot.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It's very useful to know that the paid hours are from 09:00 until 19:00. Are there street only allowed for residents in Paris and how do you spot them? Like this in UK http://images.moneysavingexpert.com/images/ParkingPermit.jpg

Comment: @SERPRO I know this from the UK or the Netherlands but as far as I know, there is nothing like that in Paris, which is why I am saying that it's relatively unrestricted. In fact, it's the other way around: There are some streets opened to visitors but not to residents.